# return an element to its starting position after .stop() is activated

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am writting a very cool jquery plugin and I'm finding myself snagged on this last bit. basically I'm animating an element on mouseenter and mouseleave. A good example can be found in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ACArUJi/1/edit?html,output) everything works well except when you hover over the back button before the go button has finished its animation it will move the image off screen. Assuming I know the starting location of the element, is there a way to keep the element from animating past its original location even if the animation is stopped early? I need to use `.stop()` for the animation. Maybe this is something easy that I'm just overlooking.

Code snippet from the jsbin link:

```
// Start animation
$( "#go" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( ".block" ).stop().animate({ left: "+=100px" }, 2000 );
});
// Start animation in the opposite direction
$( "#back" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $( ".block" ).stop().animate({ left: "-=100px" }, 2000 );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) accepts arguments that control how the animation is left. You may want to use `.stop(true, true)`, which jumps the animation to the end when stopping it:

```
$( ".block" ).stop(true, true).animate({ left: "+=100px" }, 2000 );
```

...but it might be a bit jumpy.

Alternately, as you say you know where the element starts, just return it there:

```
$( ".block" ).stop().css(originalPosition).animate({ left: "+=100px" }, 2000 );
```

...where `originalPosition` is an object with the properties `left` and `top`, presumably. That might be a bit jumpy as well, it depends on the specifics of your use case.

**Or** as, again, you have the original position, you could just animate back to that position (or forward to that position + 100px, depending).

Comment: true, true didnt do it but did return some hilarious results. however the second example is spot on in fact i cant believe i looked over it. maybe it's time to call it a day. thanks mate!